# Could not find generator rspec_model issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to create an rspec for my model User but every time I run:

```
rails g rspec_model User
```

I get Could not find generator rspec_model.

I checked another stackoverflow thread and it said make sure I have the gem 'rspec-rails' and I do. What am I doing wrong? Here's my gemfile:

```
group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'rspec', '2.0.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.1'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use (once):

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

It will create the various files and the spec directory.
You will then need to, for example, create the models directory and start creating specs in that directory.

Once you configure your application for rspec, script/rails generate ModelName will also create the rspec skeleton files I believe.

Comment: I did that already. But my User model was already created before I installed rspec. So is there a way to add a spec test to my User model now via console?

Comment: I would just create/edit the file manually.  dop u need a User example?

Comment: Well here it is anyway: `cat spec/models/user_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper.rb'

describe User do

  context "is valid" do
    subject { Factory.build(:user) }
    it { should be_valid }
    it { should belong_to(:role) }
    it { should have_many :user_memberships }
...
  end

  context "admin user is valid" do
    subject { Factory.build(:admin_user) }
    it { should be_valid }
  end
  context "country_manager is valid" do
    subject { Factory.build(:country_manager_user) }
    it { should be_valid }
  end

  end
end
`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/tree/4c8cdaef2c6f3dda29d45b7900f0b00335eeec84/lib/generators/rspec/model

```
rails g rspec:model Movie
rails g rspec:model Movie  --fixture  #tested in rails 3.1 for rspec 2.8.0
```