# how to generate rspec model in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could not find generator rspec_model issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762748/could-not-find-generator-rspec-model-issue)

is there any command to generate the model for Rspec without generating any migration and fixture for rails 3, and is it possible to generate the rspec_model after building the project
with same app/model?

Answer (score 1):

The only generator in the `rspec-rails` gem is `rspec:install`.

Reading: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#generators

When running `rspec:install`, it's not going to create `spec/model/...` files for your existing models, but there is no proble with you running `rspec:install` on an existing application.

Reading: [Could not find generator rspec_model issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762748/could-not-find-generator-rspec-model-issue)

It's really very easy to create your own `spec/model/...` files; all they need is

```
require 'rspec_helpers'
```

at the top.